Looking for series: Jungle Theme - Blond girl changes with mud into cat-ish animal with claws
So I've been looking for years for this series that I cannot remember.
Some Info:
It's a 
 - jungle theme.
 - A blond girl ( Main Char ) ( looks a lot like the girl from The Lost World ( dinosaur series)
 - When she covers herself in mud, she changes into this animal ( with claws, some sort of cat-alike dark/black )
 - It's in color , not B/W
 - She becomes friend with a male from the ' civilized world ' trying to save the jungle and animals.
 - She lives by herself in the jungle
 - It's not a movie , it's a serie , there should be multiple episodes.
Thanks in advance

This would be Sheena the TV Series it's about Sheena (a Tarzan like female character) The TV series added the ability to transform into animals which she would cover herself in mud for at least one of the animals. Here is a scene of her morphing I can't find one of the dark animal that needs the mud though 



Yup that's it thanks you have no idea how happy I am right now!
